# Python code equivalent of Java code not working as expected

Tags: java, python

I am sending a request to a server to get certain information. It works in the Java code perfectly fine but i have to convert it to Python code.

**Java code to perform the server request**

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://someWebsite.com/" + this.url +
                    "?d=android&v=1.9.0&time=" + this.getCurrentTicks() +
                    "&dummy=" + this.getCurrentDummy() + "&s=" + this.hash);

// Request headers
httppost.addHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "POST");
httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.application.btb4-v1.0+json");
httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "token " + this.authToken);
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

// Request body
String json = "{\"ad_id\":\"" + this.adId + "\",\"user_id\":\"" + this.userId + "\"}";
StringEntity entityBody = new StringEntity(json);
//System.out.println(entityBody);
httppost.setEntity(entityBody);

//Execute and get the response
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

**Python code attempt One**

```
URL = "https://tt2.someWebsite.com/{requestPath}?d=android&v={version}&time={currentTicks}&dummy={dummy}&s={hashValue}"
URL = URL.format(requestPath  = requestPath,
                 version      = self.version,
                 currentTicks = self.get_ticks(),
                 dummy        = self.get_dummy(),
                 hashValue    = self.get_hash_value()
                 )

data = {"ad_id": self.adID,
    "user_id": self.userID}

serverRequest = urllib.request.Request(URL)
serverRequest.add_header("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "POST")
serverRequest.add_header("Accept", "application/vnd.application.btb4-v1.0+json")
serverRequest.add_header("Authorization", "token " + self.authToken)
serverRequest.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(serverRequest, data = json.dumps(data))
content  = response.read()
```

**Python code attempt two**

```
URL = "https://tt2.someWebsite.com/{requestPath}?d=android&v={version}&time={currentTicks}&dummy={dummy}&s={hashValue}"
URL = URL.format(requestPath  = requestPath,
                 version      = self.version,
                 currentTicks = self.get_ticks(),
                 dummy        = self.get_dummy(),
                 hashValue    = self.get_hash_value()
                 )

data = {"ad_id": self.adID,
     "user_id": self.userID}

headers = {"X-HTTP-Method-Override": "POST",
           "Accept": "application/vnd.application.btb4-v1.0+json",
           "Authorization": "token " + self.authToken,
           "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}

r = requests.post(URL, data = json.dumps(data), headers = headers)
```

I don't understand what i am missing? Both python examples receive error 400

Comment: 400 is a bad request.  You sure you're not messing up the request somehow?  What exactly are you sending over the wire and how does it differ from the Java version?

Comment: How about `r = requests.post(URL, data=data, headers=headers)`? You shouldn't be passing `data` as json serialized string.

Comment: @Makoto the code shown is the request code...

Comment: I would also recommend either printing both the url and the data before sending it or putting a breakpoint and ensuring that you are sending what you think you are sending... you can also use something like postman to watch the actual queries of both requests to try and see how else they might differ (ie user-agent header?)

Comment: Yes, but I'm not in a position to be able to execute that Python script right this instant.  Can you tell me what request is going over the wire and if it differs (at all) from the Java request?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule same result

Comment: @Makoto the request is exactly the same. The entire URL is the same

Comment: That doesn't make sense, because you claim to get a 400 from the Python code and not the Java.

Comment: @Makoto https://pastebin.com/yBWTuhRk Top is Java bottom is Python

Comment: Are there any differences in the headers you're sending, the MIME-types you're passing along, the credentials, etc?

Comment: nope, all the headers i send are shown. everything i am sending is in those examples

Comment: This is the return from the java https://pastebin.com/tysJv39K the python simpily return http code 400

Comment: It might be easier to print out the literal HTTP request sent. I think the problem is the Java code is sending JSON as the request body, while the Python is sending something else in the body. The server is sending a 400 Bad Request because the request is not what it expects.

Comment: @wmorrell what would you like me to print out?

Comment: `print(r.request.body)`

Comment: output: ```ad_id=ca463df5-9a94-475-bbd9-89ddb883ca11&user_id=cbee9101-792e-47c7-a0e9-6aesa22d6a39```

Comment: Yep. That is not JSON. Your Java code is sending JSON in the request body, your Python code is sending form-encoded parameters.

Comment: edit: i added back json.dumps(data) and it did output a JSON ```{"ad_id": "ca463d55-9a94-475-bbd9-89ddb8833a11", "user_id": "cbee9131-792e-47c7-a0e9-6ae4a22d6a39"}```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152576/discussion-between-wmorrell-and-joshua-nixon).

Answer (score 0):

The data kwarg to `requests.post` expects to make a form-encoded post. Try using `requests.post(URL, data=BytesIO(json.dumps(data)), headers=headers)`. Be sure to `from io import BytesIO`.

Comment: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Ah, Python 3. Maybe do `from io import StringIO` and `entity = StringIO()` and `json.dump(data, entity)`, then put `entity` in the kwarg.